# How to update a document in ElasticSearch while using external versioning

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to perform an upsert in Elasticsearch 7.9 using external versioning (time-based versioning).
I try to perform the update API but when specifying the `version` and `version_type=external`.

```
indexName/_update/id?version=1234568&version_type=external
{
  "doc": {...},
  "doc_as_upsert": true
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> Validation Failed: 1: internal versioning can not be used for optimistic concurrency control. Please use `if_seq_no` and `if_primary_term` instead

But I'm **not** using internal versioning here - why does it give this error?
Does the update API not support providing version this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is not possible to use external versioning when 'updating' a document in ElasticSearch. The documentation does not specify this explicitly, but provides no options to provide an external version.